# Oracle shows strange tables with noSYSTEM User

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created an Oracle DB.
With the user `SYSTEM` I created a tablespace and another user with CONNET and DBA roles, associated with this tablespace, called `PP`. Then with this user I have created some tables.

Well, when i do a connection to the database with the user `PP` in `SQL Developer` it shows me only the tables that I create with this user. Thats ok.

The problems comes when I do a connection with other application, using aswell the same user `PP`. It show me the tables I've created, and some more, rather a lot of them.

**Examples:**

```
ALL$AW_CUBE_ENABLED_HIERCOMBO
APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_IR_COMP
REPCAT$_RESOL_STATS_CONTROL
SCHEDULER_JOB_ARGS_TBL
WWV_FLOW_AUTHORIZED_URLS
....
```

I suppose this tables are from system or sys user. 
Why can I see them with my user `PP`?
How can I do to hide them?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: They look like public synonyms. Check the owner of those objects, then you'll know. Most probably SQL Developer  filters them out and your "*other application*" doesn't (it probably just displays the result of `select * from all_objects`). If you told us what that "*other application*" is you might get better answers.

Comment: The other aplication is a SCADA that has a DataBase Browser util where you can see all your database conections with its tables.

Comment: I have tried to create another user with only CONNECT and RESOURCE roles but the results are the same.